# What am I doing wrong here? I made another package in the same project called img and put a png file in there, but I get this error

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

Ok, so here's the script for my Login.fxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="620.0"     xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"     fx:controller="application.MainController">
   <children>
      <Button layoutX="94.0" layoutY="230.0" mnemonicParsing="false"     onAction="#Login" text="Login">
         <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <TextField fx:id="txtUsername" layoutX="45.0" layoutY="78.0"     promptText="Username">
         <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </TextField>
      <PasswordField fx:id="txtPassword" layoutX="45.0" layoutY="131.0"     promptText="Password">
         <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </PasswordField>
      <Label fx:id="lblStatus" layoutX="21.0" layoutY="32.0" prefHeight="27.0"     prefWidth="263.0" text="Status" textFill="RED">
         <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <ImageView fitHeight="263.0" fitWidth="318.0" layoutX="284.0"     layoutY="14.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" ></ImageView>
       <image>
       <Image url = "img/Dantheman_outside.png"></Image>
       </image>
      </ImageView>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

And here's the error message:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/eene1/workspace/LoginFx/bin/application/Login.fxml:34

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
at application._Main.start(_Main.java:15)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot determine type for property.
at com.sun.javafx.fxml.BeanAdapter.getSetterMethod(BeanAdapter.java:177)
at com.sun.javafx.fxml.BeanAdapter.isReadOnly(BeanAdapter.java:305)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$PropertyElement.<init>(FXMLLoader.java:1368)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.createElement(FXMLLoader.java:2731)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2704)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
... 17 more
```

How do I fix this? It's really annoying and it doesn't make any sense. Thanks in advance. I also have to type some more stuff so that it will let me post this question. Just ignore this extra sentence

Comment: Is your `Image` element supposed to be inside of another `Image` element?

Comment: Try also to rename the package if your package's name id project the package for images should be named project.images

Answer (score 1):

Your FXML is misformed. You close the `<ImageView>` element on the same line you start it:

```xml
<ImageView fitHeight="263.0" ... ></ImageView>
```

and consequently the following `<image>` property element is outside of the `<ImageView>` element. (The parser is going to look at the immediate parent of `<image>`, which is, incorrectly, `<children>`. This refers to an `ObservableList`, so the parser tries to find a `setImage(...)` method in `ObservableList`; since it can't find one, you get an error.)

Assuming the path to the image is correct (i.e. `Dantheman_outside.png` is in the `application.img` package), simply removing the extraneous `</ImageView>` should fix the issue:

```xml
<ImageView fitHeight="263.0" ... >
   <image>
   <Image url = "img/Dantheman_outside.png"></Image>
   </image>
</ImageView>
```